# Sending files like a form with ocaml-curl

Tags: curl, ocaml, multipartform-data

I'm working on a little tool to upload my school work on the dedicated server my school provides, and I've decided to use `ocaml` and `ocurl`, an `ocaml` wrapper for `libcurl`.
I'm able to retrieve do everything I want from the command line (using curl), but can't upload the file with ocurl.

I think this is because the server page expects `multipart/form-data` as then content type. After reading the `libcurl` documentation I used `curl_formadd()` (and that's what I do from command line), but ocurl is not able to do that (I did not find anything like this in `curl.ml`)

Working curl command line:

```
curl -v "myhost/upload2.php" --form "fichier1= @file.tar.gz" --form "MAX_FILE_SIZE=1000000" -b cookie
```

Response

```
> POST /upload2.php HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.32.0
> Host: myhost
> Accept: */*
> Cookie: PHPSESSID=4qbihrkhode23902q1v988a114; cookie_test=1
> Content-Length: 10563
> Expect: 100-continue
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------53aa2e4a08d1f7c0
> 
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Wed, 23 Oct 2013 17:34:21 GMT
* Server Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze17
< Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
< Pragma: no-cache
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Content-Length: 2265
< Content-Type: text/html
<
```

My closest non-working `ocaml` code

```
let fetch connection url =
Printf.printf "Retriving %s ...\n" (url);
flush stdout;
Curl.set_url connection url;
Curl.perform connection;
Curl.set_post connection false
in
Curl.global_init Curl.CURLINIT_GLOBALALL;
let connection = Curl.init() in
Curl.set_verbose connection true;  
let curl_file_option = Curl.CURLFORM_FILECONTENT("fichier1","file.tar.gz",Curl.CONTENTTYPE "application/x-tar") in                                     
Curl.set_maxfilesize connection (Int32.of_int 1000000);                                                                                                      
Curl.set_httppost connection [curl_file_option];
fetch connection (baseURL^"upload2.php");
;;
```

Which does absolutely nothing but using 100% CPU

Finally, the question is : could you help me building my own formdata function ?

Comment: How do you get your connection value ?
You have ; instead of ;; at the end, it's normal ?

Comment: I edited my code. I get connection using Curl.init() -like in the examples files provided with ocurl.

I've added printf between every lines, and it seems to block just before Curl.set_httppost.
Also, I've found [this code (l37)](https://github.com/ocaml/oasis-db/blob/master/test/TestAPI.ml) which seems to do want I want to do, but I don't see any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Please read curl manual carefully

> ```
>    CURLFORM_FILECONTENT
>           followed by a filename, causes that file to be read and its contents used as data in this part. This part does not automatically become a file upload part
>           simply because its data was read from a file.
> ```

I.e. just use CURLFORM_FILE. Though I still don't understand how your original code can cause 100% CPU.

Also, ocurl doesn't provide curl_formadd simply because it is not needed, set_httppost already takes a list.